# Changing order in QGIS layers panel?

Tags: qgis

I'm unable to change layers order in the layer tree. The 'drag and drop' stopped working and I don't know why.

There's no problem with **Layer Order Panel**; **Control rendering order** box is not checked. Restarting QGIS did not help.
I tried to reinstall program after cleaning directiories (I think I got all of them) but it also did nothing. I was using QGIS 3.4. and I'm on 3.6. now.

I'm using QGIS for basic functions, no coding. I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: This sounds like a problem you should take directly to QGIS.